# Invert a Clipping Path in Expression Blend

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, blend, clipping

I want to be able to invert a clipping path.

Rather than use the path to show parts of an object, I want to use the clipping path to hide (cut into) an object.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this just isn't possible.  I've put in a request with the blend team to think about this functionality in future releases.